# Compare NSDate objects only in terms of year month day

Tags: iphone, nsdate

If I want to use the compare method to compare two days:

```
[day1 compare:day2] == NSOrderedAscending
```

How to compare only by year-month-day?

Comment: You mean, excluding the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 86400 seconds in a day, so if you get the number of seconds since a reference date for both dates, you can divide them by 86400 and compare the two numbers.

This will give you (in `days1` and `days2`) the number of days for the dates that have passed since January 1<sup>st</sup>, 1970. You can then compare them.

```
int days1 = [date1 timeIntervalSince1970] / 86400;
int days2 = [date2 timeIntervalSince1970] / 86400;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would like to write something like:

```
if ([date1 isSameDayAs:date2]) {...}
```

You can achieve this with a simple category on NSDate, sonething like:

```
@implementation NSDate (Extensions)
- (BOOL) isSameDayAs:(NSDate *)date2
{
    int days1 = [self  timeIntervalSince1970] / 86400;
    int days2 = [date2 timeIntervalSince1970] / 86400;
    return (days1 == days2);
}
@end
```