# Comparing certain components of NSDate?

Tags: iphone, comparison, nsdate

How would I compare only the year-month-day components of 2 `NSDates`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare NSDate objects only in terms of year month day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432700/compare-nsdate-objects-only-in-terms-of-year-month-day)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So here's how you'd do it:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSInteger desiredComponents = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit);

NSDate *firstDate = ...; // one date
NSDate *secondDate = ...; // the other date

NSDateComponents *firstComponents = [calendar components:desiredComponents fromDate:firstDate];
NSDateComponents *secondComponents = [calendar components:desiredComponents fromDate:secondDate];

NSDate *truncatedFirst = [calendar dateFromComponents:firstComponents];
NSDate *truncatedSecond = [calendar dateFromComponents:secondComponents];

NSComparisonResult result = [truncatedFirst compare:truncatedSecond];
if (result == NSOrderedAscending) {
  //firstDate is before secondDate
} else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
  //firstDate is after secondDate
}  else {
  //firstDate is the same day/month/year as secondDate
}
```

Basically, we take the two dates, chop off their hours-minutes-seconds bits, and the turn them back into dates.  We then compare those dates (which no longer have a time component; only a date component) and see how they compare to eachother.

<sub>WARNING: typed in a browser and not compiled. Caveat implementor</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Check out this topic [NSDate get year/month/day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day)

Once you pull out the day/month/year, you can compare them as integers.

If you don't like that method

Instead, you could try this..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
int year = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
int month = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
int day = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
```

- And another way...

  ```
  NSDateComponents *dateComp = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

  NSInteger year = [dateComp year];

  NSInteger month = [dateComp month];

  NSInteger day = [dateComp day];
  ```

Comment: Awesome, I had read somewhere that it might not, but thank you for the verification.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 8 you can use `-compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:` method of `NSCalendar`.

Like this:

```
    NSComparisonResult comparison = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] compareDate:date1 toDate:date2 toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitDay];
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for iOS 8 or later. Makes fewer assumptions and is more concise than the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

With the the `-[NSDate compare:]` method - [NSDate Compare Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)